# In a bash script how can i get a random answer to a to a query

Tags: bash

I am making a bash script to spoof os to random between 8-10. Heres what i have done

```
#!/bin/bash
#print Lets spoof the os range 8-10
$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 8 ))
if (?)
```

But how can i get what it answered and can execute my code according to answer.

Comment: Assign it to a variable.

Comment: shouldn't it be `mod 3`? to get nos between `0-2` and sum with `8`?

Comment: You could use `case`, see https://www.shellhacks.com/case-statement-bash-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is using the `case` syntax :

```
#!/bin/bash

#print Lets spoof the os range 8-10
NB=$(( ( RANDOM % 3 )  + 8 )) # % 3 to have 0, 1 or 2

case $NB in
   '8')
      echo "It's 8"
      ;;
   '9')
      echo "It's 9"
      ;;
   '10')
      echo "It's 10"
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me